# Update two jSWING forms in the same time

Tags: java, jframe

Is there any way to pass value from one jFrame to another but on little differnt way.

Jframe1 is active and inside jframe I receive some data from RS232 and they are displayed in JTextField. In the same time I want to have opened another jframe and show also received data.

Is this possible? What is the best approach for that? I was thinking about somekind of global array which act as holder of received value and in jframe2 using threading I will read those data and do something with them.

Answer (score 0):

Store that data in a String (anything can go in a String as long as you put quotes around it), and do whatever you want with it on the other JFrame, like draw it to the screen or add it to a TextField.

Comment: This is clear but the problem is how to have two frames opened in the same time and show the same data in both of them?

Comment: Store the String, and draw it to both; what's the problem?